# SecureStorage not installed, but it is in Ionic3

Tags: ionic-framework, npm, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I am migrating [Storage](https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/) to [SecureStorage](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/secure-storage/). The normal storage worked fine, but I have problems with secure storage on all platforms.

I installed the plugin like [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/secure-storage/) described. But if I run the app in the browser or on Android, I get following errors:

```
plugin_not_installed
(...)
ERROR Error: "Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this.storage is undefined
[42]/DataProvider.prototype.getLoginData
```

I imported SecureStorage as Provider into `app.module.ts`.

`app.component.ts` looks like this:

```js
constructor(public platform: Platform, public statusBar: StatusBar, public splashScreen: SplashScreen, private dataProvider: DataProvider, private restProvider: RestProvider) {
    this.initializeApp();

     // ...
  }

initializeApp() {
  this.platform.ready().then(() => {
    this.statusBar.styleDefault();

    this.dataProvider.getLoginData().then((loginData) => {
      console.log(loginData);
    }, (error) => {
      console.error(error);
  });
}
```

And DataProvider looks like this:

```js
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {SecureStorage, SecureStorageObject} from '@ionic-native/secure-storage';


/**
 * @see https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/secure-storage/
 * @see https://github.com/Crypho/cordova-plugin-secure-storage
 */
@Injectable()
export class DataProvider {

  storage: SecureStorageObject;

  constructor(private secureStorage: SecureStorage) {
    this.secureStorage.create('com.mydomain.myapp').then((storage: SecureStorageObject) => {
      DevProvider.logDebugMsg('secureStorage created');
      this.storage = storage;
    }, (error) => {
      console.error('creating secureStorage failed: ', error); // output is: plugin_not_installed
    });
  }

  getLoginData() {
    return this.storage.get('loginData');
  }
}
```

What's wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you added it to providers in app.module.ts?

Comment: Yes. I did. I can also see the plugin listed in `ionic cordova plugin list`. cordova-plugin-secure-storage 2.6.8 "SecureStorage"

Comment: Can you see in console that secureStorage initiation was completed ('secureStorage created' from your code) before error occurs? I am guesing that you my try to access storage before it is ready.

Comment: The first error is "creating secureStorage failed:  plugin_not_installed". That's from the catch because creating is failed. The constructor of DataProvider should be executed after calling this class the first time after device is ready or not?

Comment: This is the full output: `Ionic Native: tried accessing the SecureStorage plugin but it's not installed. util.js:53
Install the SecureStorage plugin: 'ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-secure-storage' util.js:56
Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode. core.js:3688
creating secureStorage failed:  plugin_not_installed data.ts:27:6
home.ionViewDidLoad() dev.ts:21:8
ERROR TypeError: "this.storage is undefined"
getLoginData Ionic Native: deviceready event fired after 1309 ms.` The deviceready event fired as the latest?

Comment: dataProvider constructor will be called just after device is ready but `secureStorage.create` returns promise and `getLoginData` will be called regardless if create was completed. Just for the sake of checking scenario try to remove geLoginData from initializeApp and call it within dataProvider constructor (after `this.storage = storage;` )

Comment: I wrapped everything in the constructor of DataProvider with `platform.ready().then( () => { // code }`. The secure storage now is created. So I have a lifecycle / design issue.

Comment: But how can I be sure that secure storage is created before called other methods on it?

Comment: I use events. Publish event when storage is successfully created and subscribe to this event. When event occurs and only then execute your login logic.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks.